# Canvas size - text rendering

Tags: java, text, rendering, 2d, awt

Is there any way how to determine the optimal canvas size for text rendering?

The input is a string with newlines, I want to contruct the canvas to fit (no insets) while using both font types - proportional and non-proportional, these types will be never mixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Java Tutorial Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)

```
 FontMetrics metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
 int hgt = metrics.getHeight();
 int adv = metrics.stringWidth(text);
 Dimension size = new Dimension(adv+2, hgt+2);
```

You probably need to do this line by line of your text and detect whether your font changes between lines.